# Sentry raven test successful, but nothing on the server

Tags: sentry

When I run `./manage.py raven test` I get this output:

```
Client configuration:
  servers        : ['http://sentry.myserver.com/api/6/store/']
  project        : 6
  public_key     : 5f24455730cb420092d39b9fe43687a5
  secret_key     : d7dc948032cb4b5fb3db4511c78c4b58

Sending a test message... success!
Event ID was 'd0088a4b64424d19bd1f41d5bd6fe89f'
```

When I check my server, I don't see any events for that project. I've double checked that my RAVEN_CONFIG matches that of the project on myserver (I copied and pasted the config directly from the settings in Sentry for that project).

I can't find where sentry logs any errors for itself. Does it have a log file? I haven't found anything in the sentry docs about a log file for Sentry.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: I realized that I did not have the sentry worker running.

http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#starting-the-workers